# Syntax SQL (WHERE,AND,LIKE)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What is wrong with this syntax?

`select * from registered_members where username = '$username' AND LIKE '%LOL%'`

Comment: your statement is vulnerable to sql injection .......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a column name between "AND" & "LIKE"

ie

```
    SELECT * FROM Registered_Members WHERE UserName = '$username' AND UserName LIKE '%LOL%'
```

Comment: Thank you ... Not worked I knew where wrong.

With Respect,
Mihai Ionita

Answer (score 10):

You're not specifying which column to compare with `LIKE`.

```
"select * from registered_members where username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($username) . "' and username like '%LOL%'"
```

Also you need to protect yourself from SQL injection... You should really use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to adding the column name to search, you should escape the `$username` variable to prevent SQL injection:  See [bobby-tables.com](http://bobby-tables.com/).  Otherwise as you have written it, people could execute arbitrary SQL code in your page.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from registered_members where username = '$username' AND username LIKE '%LOL%'
```